# Mean line from several lines

Tags: linear-algebra

i want to find the average line from different line segments.
I don't know how to do this and also don't know how to descripe it specifically. So I'll give you an example:
If a have two lines with the following points:
(start(0/7)end(2/1)) and (start(4/1)end(6/7)) i want a vertical line, which goes through (3/1)

The same could happen that a want a parallel line.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Find the equation of the first line in the form $y=ax+b$, do the same for the second line, add them, and divide by 2.

Comment: The problem is, that this equation will not work, if my line is vertical. Then a will be infinite.
So I guess, that i will have to work with vectors.

To be specific: I don't know the lines before the calculation of the average line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of an "average line segment" is not well defined until you define it.  One approach is to average the "first end points" of all the segments (however you define that-do they come with direction), average the "second end points" and draw the segment between them.  These averages are well defined.  Maybe that meets you needs.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, since you think the vertical line is the average between those two lines, you should consider the vertical coordinate as your variable. So you should find the parameters $a_1,\ a_2,\ b_1$ and $b_2$ in the equations $x_1=a_1y+b_1$ and $x_2=a_2y+b_2$.

For the example points you give you will find that $x_1 = -\frac{1}{3}y+\frac{7}{3}$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{3}y+\frac{11}{3}$. Adding them and subsequently dividing by $2$ gives the average $x_{avg} = 3$, independent of $y$. This is the vertical line you seek.